# Find test name in Vim Script

Tags: vim

I've written a simple script that works but I'm looking for a better implementation.

Here is my ideal scenario.  I'm sitting in a test file that contains many tests like this:

```
  def test_cleans_number
    number = PhoneNumber.new("(123) 456-7890").number
    assert_equal "1234567890", number
  end

  def test_cleans_a_different_number
    number = PhoneNumber.new("(987) 654-3210").number
    assert_equal "9876543210", number
  end

  def test_cleans_number_with_dots
    number = PhoneNumber.new("456.123.7890").number
    assert_equal "4561237890", number
  end
```

I've written this vim script which allows me to put my cursor on the definition line of the test and it will run that test and that test only:

```
function! RunNearestTest()
  let line = getline('.')
  let test_name = substitute(line, 'def ', "", "g")
  exec ":!ruby " . @% . " -n " . test_name
endfunction

" run test runner
map <leader>T :call RunNearestTest()<cr>
```

If it's not obvious from the script, I need the test name in order to run that test specifically.  In the first example the test name is `test_cleans_number`.

As I said, this works fine but what I'd like to do is be on any line in the test and it would know to jump to the previous `def`, get the `test_name` and then run the execution. I thought `searchpair()` would be my goto here but alas I can't find enough documentation on it.

I'm happy to provide any files or extras you might need here, thank you!

Comment: Sidebar: `[m`/`]m` will move to the previous/next method definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `search()` function returns the number of the matching line:

```
function! RunNearestTest()
  let line_text = getline(search('def ', 'bcW'))
  let test_name = substitute(line_text, 'def ', "", "g")
  exec ":!ruby " . @% . " -n " . test_name
endfunction
```

See `:help search()`.

Comment: Ah-ha!  You're just missing one requirement of mine, after I get the line # produced by `search`, I need to run let `getline` on it in order to get the text.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Oops! I forgot that part for some reason.